# Trying to draw a graph with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I found an example of a nice graph in the pgfplots manual, and am trying to graphmy own function with it. However, when I try to graph `x^2`, I seem to get `x^3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-1.2:1.2]
\draw[very thin,color=gray,style=dashed] (-3,-3) grid (3,3);
\draw[->] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[above] {$f(x)$};
\draw[color=blue] plot (\x,{(\x)^2-2(\x)-2}) node[right] {$f(x)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Would anyone happen to know why this isn't working properly?

Comment: You're missing a multiplication sign after the 2:\draw[color=blue] plot (\x,{(\x)^2-2*(\x)-2}) node[right] {$f(x)$}; works fine.

Comment: You are not using the commands from pgfplots, but beside this you are missing a multiplication sign: `{(\x)^2-2*(\x)-2}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you! What do you mean I'm not using the commands from pgfplots, though?

Comment: with pgfplots you should use the `axis` environment and the `\addplot` command. Your code doesn't need pgfplots, only tikz.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was all about a typo and has nothing to do with TeX.

Comment: @Symbol1 well, I disagree because it's not a typo (I didn't know that I needed to put a star) and isn't it about TeX? but go ahead.

Comment: @SkeletonBow Well since you have gotten the answer and there is not going to be any meaningful, useful answer, I would like to make up some reason to remove this question from **Unanswered** list.

Comment: @Symbol1 yes, I understand. I could also simply delete it. Should I do that?

Comment: Unless you really really really want to do so :P    But in this case I want to see other experienced community members' reaction.

Comment: Okay, sure! Maybe I'll wait for a day or something.